# Formula for number of squares fitting into a right angle triangle

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry, tessellations

Is there a known formula for the number of squares of a certain size that would fit into a right angled triangle?

Comment: Here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-number-of-squares-that-can-be-fit-in-a-right-angle-isosceles-triangle/

Comment: suppose the area of right triangle is an integer n, that does not mean you can fit n unit square in. There will be half right triangles along hypotenuse. you can see that by drawing.